# SQL error as a result of rewriting a query using subquery into a query using join

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

The original query:

```
SELECT      o.offering_number,
        o.english_description,
        o.french_description,
        fop.price_amount,
        fop.price_type_code,
        fop.price_status_code,
        fop.offering_id,
        (SELECT fop1.price_amount from facility_offering_price fop1
                WHERE fop.offering_id = fop1.Offering_Id
                    AND fop1.price_type_code = 5
                AND fop1.price_status_code = 3
            ) as 'priceAmount'
            from facility_offering_price fop
            join offering o on fop.offering_id = o.offering_id
                WHERE fop.price_start_date = '15-10-28'
                AND fop.price_status_code IN (1,2)
                /*AND (price_status_code IS NULL)*/
                AND fop.price_type_code = 5
                /*AND (o.offering_number IS NULL)*/
                    ORDER BY o.offering_number ASC, fop.price_sequence_number ASC;
```

It produces a result of one entry.

The result query:

```
SELECT      o.offering_number,
        o.english_description,
        o.french_description,
        fop.price_amount,
        fop2.price_amount,
        fop.price_type_code,
        fop.offering_id,
        fop2.offering_id
            from facility_offering_price fop
            join offering o on fop.offering_id = o.offering_id
            inner join
                (select
                    fop1.offering_id,
                    fop1.price_amount
                            from facility_offering_price fop1
                            WHERE fop1.price_type_code = 5
                            AND fop1.price_status_code = 3
                ) fop2 on fop.offering_id = fop2.offering_id
                WHERE fop.price_start_date = '15-10-28'
                AND fop.price_status_code IN (1,2)
                /*AND (price_status_code IS NULL)*/
                AND fop.price_type_code = 5
                /*AND (o.offering_number IS NULL)*/
                    ORDER BY o.offering_number ASC, fop.price_sequence_number ASC;
```

It's result set is empty. However, an entry is found if I ask for fop1.price_status_code = 1.

Unable to wrap my head around this one I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems data driven.  SQL is nice for being modular, if you run your subquery on it's own, do you get data?  If you remove all where clauses, do you get data?  if you change the joins to left joins, do you get data?    Hard to troubleshoot data issues without data examples beyond that.

Comment: Hard to believe this.  You should create a fiddle or rextester that shows the issue.

Comment: Second read and agree with Aaron, this looks right...something odd at play

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LEFT JOIN` instead. The conversion from `SELECT a, subquery AS val FROM ...` to a join is more accurately reflected that way. The original query would return rows with NULL `val` when the subquery has no results; your version ends up omitting such rows completely.